# Iterate over an object to see which active days matches per id

Tags: javascript, angular

Consider the array of objects below,

```
const resource = [
    {
        id: 'tony',
        shiftday: [
            {active: '1', code: 'Sun'},
            {active: '1', code: 'Mon'},
            {active: '1', code: 'Tue'},
            {active: '1', code: 'Wed'},
            {active: '1', code: 'Thu'},
            {active: '1', code: 'Fri'},
            {active: '1', code: 'Sat'},
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 'alex',
        shiftday: [
            {active: '0', code: 'Sun'},
            {active: '1', code: 'Mon'},
            {active: '1', code: 'Tue'},
            {active: '0', code: 'Wed'},
            {active: '1', code: 'Thu'},
            {active: '1', code: 'Fri'},
            {active: '0', code: 'Sat'},
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 'trey',
        shiftday: [
            {active: '0', code: 'Sun'},
            {active: '1', code: 'Mon'},
            {active: '0', code: 'Tue'},
            {active: '1', code: 'Wed'},
            {active: '0', code: 'Thu'},
            {active: '1', code: 'Fri'},
            {active: '0', code: 'Sat'},
        ]
    },
]
```

I need to get all values that has active day set to 1 (selected) and match it to the other id's. And to be able to say that which id's have matching active days.

Comment: where is your attempt? what issues are you facing? Please share those so that someone can help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can achieve it. I just printed activeDays, instead, you can store it in a separate array, and reuse it after the loop.

```
const neededArrayOfIds = ['trey']; // <- Declare array of needed IDs

resource.forEach(elm => {
  if (neededArrayOfIds.includes(elm.id)) {
    const activeDays = elm.shiftday.filter(day => day.active == 1)
    console.log(activeDays)
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks! This looks like something I need, I do need to iterate it over length instead of id though.

Answer (score 1):

It give active day  array of object.

```js
 const activeDays = resource.map(item => item.shiftday.filter(day => day.active === '1'));
 console.log(activeDay);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
const filteredArr = resource.map((item) => {
 const filteredShiftDays = item.shiftday.filter((state) = state.active === '1');

 return {
  id: item.id,
  active: filteredShiftDays
 };
});
```

It returns all active days including the ID which days belongs to whom.